# Existence of a non-Eulerian atomistic lattice with this property on the Möbius function

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, sage

Let $L$ be a finite lattice with least element $\hat{0}$, greatest element $\hat{1}$, and Möbius function $\mu$.

*Question 1*: What class of lattices the following property characterizes? $$\mu(\hat{0},a)=\mu(\hat{0},\hat{1})\mu(a,\hat{1}), \ \forall a \in L$$ It follows that $\mu(\hat{0},\hat{1}) = \pm1$.

*Remark*: It is satisfied by any boolean lattice, more generally by the face lattice of any convex polytope (as suggested by John Shareshian), and more generally by any [Eulerian lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_poset).
*Proof*: An Eulerian lattice is a graded lattice $L$ such that for any $a,b \in L$ with $a \le b$, we have $\mu(a,b)= (-1)^{|b|-|a|} $, with $a \mapsto |a|$ the rank function. The result is immediate. $\square$

*Question 2*: Is there a non-Eulerian lattice with the above property on the Möbius function?
**Yes**, see the answer of John Machacek.

As suggested by Sam Hopkins:
*Question 3*: Is there a non-Eulerian *atomistic* lattice with the above property on the Möbius function?
*No* for $|L| \le 13$, as checked by the following Sage program (using [these lists](http://www.shsu.edu/mem037/Lattices.html) of Martin Malandro):

```
from itertools import product
def relationtest(L,n):
    for l in L:
        P=Poset((range(n),l))
        b = P.bottom()
        t = P.top()
        if all(P.moebius_function(b,x) == P.moebius_function(b,t)*P.moebius_function(x,t) for x in P):
            L=LatticePoset(P)
            if L.is_atomic():
                if not L.is_graded():
                    print(P.cover_relations())
                if L.is_graded():
                    for x, y in product(P, P):
                        if P.compare_elements(x,y)==-1:
                            if not P.moebius_function(x,y)==(-1)^(P.rank(y)-P.rank(x)):
                                print(P.cover_relations())
                                break
```

Are the small atomistic lattices listed somewhere?

Comment: Hi Sebastien,  how about the face lattice of an arbitrary polytope?

Comment: Hi John, you are right, it works for some non-simplex polytopes I tried. I don't know if it works for any arbitrary polytope, or if we need convexity. In fact, I'm interested to know all the lattices satisfying this property, so I hope you will not mind if I improve the post.

Comment: You might want to read about Eulerian posets in Chapter 3 of Richard Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics".

Answer (score 4):

I found the following example with [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/). Below is the Hasse diagram and verification in SageMath that the poset is a lattice which is not Eulerian (in fact not graded) that satisfies the desired Möbius function condition. I have nothing more enlightening to say currently, but I'll post this example since it answers the second question about a non-Eulerian example and will perhaps helps toward an answer to the first question about characterizing such lattices.

[image: Hasse]

```
sage: P = Poset(([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 7], [3, 4], [4, 8], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 8], [7, 8]]))
sage: b = P.bottom()
sage: t = P.top()
sage: P.is_lattice()
True
sage: P.is_graded()
False
sage: all(P.moebius_function(b,x) == P.moebius_function(b,t)*P.moebius_function(x,t) for x in P)
True
```

Comment: Yes! From your example I deduce the following process generating new lattices with the expected property: take a lattice $L$ with this property (for example an Eulerian lattice), and take two elements $a, b \in L$ with  $$\hat{0} < a \lessdot b < \hat{1}.$$ Create a new lattice $\tilde{L}$ by adding an extra element $c$ between $a$ and $b$. By construction $$\mu_{\tilde{L}}(\hat{0},c) = \mu_{\tilde{L}}(c,\hat{1}) = 0,$$ and the rest is unchanged, so  $\tilde{L}$ works also. Your example is this process applied to $B_3$.

Comment: *Question*: Is there an example which does not come the application finitely many times of this process to an Eulerian lattice? For example, a lattice $L$ having an element $a$ such that $\mu(\hat{0},a) \not \in \{ -1,0,1  \}$.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: for starters, you could ask if every *atomistic* lattice satisfying your condition is Eulerian.

Comment: SebastienPalcoux, nice construction. I just ran a computer search but did not have much time to actually think. Glad you were able to make something of it.

@SamHopkins, yes I think it would be interesting to find conditions which force Eulerian (or don't).

Comment: @JohnMachacek: Is the list of small (atomistic) lattices available on SageMath?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux not that I know of. I only know Posets(n) will give a list of posets on n elements up to isomorphism. That could be a start, but then you would need to check for properties you want.

Comment: @JohnMachacek: the lattices on <=15 nodes are listed [here](http://www.shsu.edu/mem037/Lattices.html).